# Regex for selecting files in 6 hour intervals

Tags: regex

I have a list of files with the timestamp in the file name, named in the form:

```
file_year-month-date-hour-minute.something.gz.
```

For instance there are files named

```
file_2013-06-17-00-05.something.gz 
file_2013-06-17-00-10.something.gz
```

I need to select files in 6 hour intervals with a regex. 
Selecting "file_year-month-date*" gives me daily files, but not sure how to filter down to 6 hour chunks.

Comment: Honestly, it doesn't seem like a regular expression is the right mechanism to use for this. Why not simply parse the filenames into an indexable list of timestamps? Then you can group, filter and query with great flexibility.

Comment: regex is for *format* validation, not *programmatic* validation.

Comment: regex can certainly be used to validate and extract $1, $2, etc. _fields_ from within a string, but it might be easier to "split" the names on _, ., and - especially if you need to do further processing and comparison of values and/or generating a Unix timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do this with RegEx if you must:

```
file_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-(?:00|06|12|18|24)-(?:[0-5][0-9])\..+?\.gz
```